# C# - Input Validation for capital letters

Tags: c#, validation

I want an input validation for a textbox with capital letters.

For text (or e.g. numbers ...) I use the following way

```
 public interface IInputValidation
    {
        bool IsValid(string input);
    }

    public class TextValidator : IInputValidation
    {
        public bool IsValid(string input)
        {
            if (input == null || input == "")
            {
                return false;
            }
            else return true;
        }
    }
```

Can I do a validation in the same way for capital letters?
Something like

```
public class CapitalLetterValidator : IInputValidation
....
```

Comment: Asking a yes or no question might not be the best idea. The answer is probably yes. Is there a concrete problem you are facing?

Comment: Define what you want to check more precisely. You only want to allow Letters in Uppercase in the input string?

Comment: This feels like a front end framework validation. Are you using something like Angular or React?

Comment: I don't know how to do the validation for capital letters

Comment: Note that your existing IsValid method is the same as `!String.IsNullOrEmpty(input)`